# How to diff files ignoring comments (lines starting with #)?

Tags: regular-expression, diff

I've two configuration files, the original from the package manager and a customized one modified by myself. I've added some comments to describe behavior.

How can I run `diff` on the configuration files, skipping the comments? A commented line is defined by:

- optional leading whitespace (tabs and spaces)
- hash sign (`#`)
- anything other character

The (simplest) regular expression skipping the first requirement would be `#.*`. I tried the `--ignore-matching-lines=RE` (`-I RE`) option of GNU diff 3.0, but I couldn't get it working with that RE. I also tried `.*#.*` and `.*\#.*` without luck. Literally putting the line (`Port 631`) as `RE` does not match anything, neither does it help to put the RE between slashes.

As suggested in [“diff” tool's flavor of regex seems lacking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072167/diff-tools-flavor-of-regex-seems-lacking/2072649#2072649), I tried `grep -G`:

```
grep -G '#.*' file
```

This seems to match the comments, but it does not work for `diff -I '#.*' file1 file2`.

So, how should this option be used? How can I make `diff` skip certain lines (in my case, comments)? Please do not suggest `grep`ing the file and comparing the temporary files.

Comment: The `-I` option causes a block to be ignored only if *all* its lines match the regexp. So you can ignore a comment-only change that way, but not the comment changes that are near a non-comment change.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks, now I get it why `diff -I` does not behave as I expected. I updated my answer with an example which clarified this behavior for me.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

According to Gilles, the `-I` option only ignores a line if nothing else inside that set matches except for the match of `-I`. I didn't fully get it until I tested it.

### The Test

Three files are involved in my test:
File **`test1`**:

```
    text
```

File **`test2`**:

```
    text
    #comment
```

File **`test3`**:

```
    changed text
    #comment
```

The commands:

```
$ # comparing files with comment-only changes
$ diff -u -I '#.*' test{1,2}
$ # comparing files with both comment and regular changes
$ diff -u -I '#.*' test{2,3}
--- test2       2011-07-20 16:38:59.717701430 +0200
+++ test3       2011-07-20 16:39:10.187701435 +0200
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-text
+changed text
 #comment
```

#### The alternative way

Since there is no answer so far explaining how to use the `-I` option correctly, I'll provide an alternative which works in bash shells:

```
diff -u -B <(grep -vE '^\s*(#|$)' test1)  <(grep -vE '^\s*(#|$)' test2)
```

- `diff -u` - unified diff

  - `-B` - ignore blank lines
- `<(command)` - a bash feature called [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) which opens a file descriptor for the command, this removes the need for a temporary file
- `grep` - command for printing lines (not) matching a pattern

  - `-v` - show non-matching lines
  - `E` - use extended regular expressions
  - `'^\s*(#|$)'` - a regular expression matching comments and empty lines

    - `^` - match the beginning of a line
    - `\s*` - match whitespace (tabs and spaces) if any
    - `(#|$)` match a hash mark, or alternatively, the end of a line

Comment: `*CHEF'S KISS*`

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
diff -b -I '^#' -I '^ #' file1 file2
```

Please note that the regex has to match the corresponding line in both files and it matches every changed line in the hunk in order to work, otherwise it'll still show the difference.

Use single quotes to protect pattern from shell expanding and to escape the regex-reserved characters (e.g. brackets).

We can read in [`diffutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Specified-Lines.html#Specified-Lines) manual:

> However, `-I` only ignores the insertion or deletion of lines that contain the regular expression if every changed line in the hunk (every insertion and every deletion) matches the regular expression.
>
> In other words, for each non-ignorable change, `diff` prints the complete set of changes in its vicinity, including the ignorable ones. You can specify more than one regular expression for lines to ignore by using more than one `-I` option. `diff` tries to match each line against each regular expression, starting with the last one given.

This behavior is also well explained by [armel here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15923606/55075).

Related: [How can I perform a diff that ignores all comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7504059/55075)

Answer (score 5):

After searching around the web, I found a method similar to Lekensteyn's.

But I want use the `diff` output as input to `patch`, and `grep -v` changes the formatting, so I can't.

Here's an improvement, maybe :

```
diff -u -B <(sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*#.*$/ /' file1)  <(sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*#.*$/ /' file2)
```

It's not perfect, but line numbers are kept in the patch file.

However, if a new line is added instead of comment line, then the comment will cause the hunk to fail while patching:

```
File test1:
  text
  #comment
  other text
File test2:
  text
  new line here
  #comment changed
  other text changed
```

Testing that data with our command:

```
$ echo -e "#!/usr/bin/sed -f\ns/^[[:blank:]]*#.*$/ /" > outcom.sed
$ echo "diff -u -B <(./outcom.sed \$1)  <(./outcom.sed \$2)" > mydiff.sh
$ chmod +x mydiff.sh outcom.sed
$ ./mydiff.sh file1 file2 > file.dif
$ cat file.dif
--- /dev/fd/63  2014-08-23 10:05:08.000000000 +0200
+++ /dev/fd/62  2014-08-23 10:05:08.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 text
+new line
  
-other text
+other text changed
```

/dev/fd/62 & /dev/fd/63 are file produced by process substitution.  The line between "+new line" and "-other text" is the default space character, which we defined in our sed expression to replace comments.

Applying that patch gives us the error :

```
$ patch -p0 file1 < file.dif 
patching file file1
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file file1.rej
```

A solution is to not use the unified diff format; so, without `-u`:

```
$ echo "diff -B <(./outcom.sed \$1)  <(./outcom.sed \$2)" > mydiff.sh
$ ./mydiff.sh file1 file2 > file.dif
$ cat file.dif
1a2
> new line
3c4
< other text
---
> other text changed
$ patch -p0 file1 < file.dif 
patching file file1
$ cat file1
text
new line
#comment
other text changed
```

Now the patch file works (no guarantees for anything more complex, though).

Comment: Your unified diff fails to apply due to the context differences. You can use `diff -U0 one two` to disable the context. For patching, there are a bunch of tools that may be better suited such as kdiff3.

Comment: Thank you for `-U0` option to disable context.
Note : kdiff3 is a graphical tool. I need automatic tool for manage git merge attributes.

Comment: `vimdiff` supports three-way merges, might be worth looking at.

Comment: to be more precise, I need a script tool for automating the git merge process with exludes in an sql script. kdiff3 and vimdiff are interactives tools, not usable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I usually ignore this clutter by either:

- Generating non-commented versions using `grep -v "^#" | cat -s` and diffing those or...
- Using `vim -d` to look at the files. The syntax highlighting takes care of making comment vs. non-comment differences quite obvious. The diff highlighting of in-line difference so you can see what values or parts of values have been changed at a glance makes this my favorite.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use to remove all commented lines -even those starting with a tab or space- and the blank ones:

```
egrep -v "^$|^[[:space:]]*#" /path/to/file
```

or you can do

```
sed -e '/^#.*/d' -e 's/#.*//g' | cat -s
```

Answer (score 0):

My open-source Linux tool 'dif' compares files while ignoring various differences such as comments.

It has many other options for ignoring whitespace or timestamps, sorting the input files, doing search/replace, ignoring certain lines, etc.

After preprocessing the input files, it runs the Linux tools meld, gvimdiff, tkdiff, or kompare on these intermediate files.

Installation is not required, just download and run the 'dif' executable from https://github.com/koknat/dif

For your use case, try the "comments" option:

```
dif file1 file2 -comments
```

If standard "diff" stdout should be used instead of a gui, add the "diff" option

```
dif file1 file2 -comments -diff
```